# How to sort the data while searching according to the ratings they get and also for not those are not rated

Tags: laravel-5.7

> I have a project of human resource management where I want to
>   display the ratings and non ratings jobseekers while searching as a
>   employer.
>
> ```
> I have tried this but this only gives jobseekers whose ratings has been set.
> ```

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $request->get('query');
        if (isset($query)) {
            $queryParam = explode(' ', $query);
        } else {
            $queryParam = null;
        }
        $jobseekers = JobSeekers::where(function ($que) use ($queryParam) {
            if (isset($queryParam)) {
                foreach ($queryParam as $queries) {
                    $que->orWhere('job_seekers.category', 'like', '%' . $queries . '%');
                    $que->orWhere('job_seekers.keywords', 'like', '%' . $queries . '%');
                    $que->orWhere('job_seekers.experience', 'like', '%' . $queries . '%');
                }
            }
        })->join('ratings', 'job_seekers.id', '=', 'ratings.js_id')
            ->groupBy('job_seekers.id')
            ->select('job_seekers.id', DB::raw('AVG( ratings.rating )  AS average_rating'))
            ->orderBy('average_rating', 'desc')
            ->get();
        return view('search.search_all', compact('jobseekers'));
    }
```

> ```
>     I have a rating table .
> ```

```
    Schema::create('ratings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('emp_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('js_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('rating')->unsigned();
        $table->longText('description')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('emp_id')->references('id')->on('employers');
        $table->foreign('js_id')->references('id')->on('job_seekers');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

> I get data of only objects whose ratings is given but not for the
>   datas that exists but has no rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `leftJoin()` instead of `join()`.

`JOIN` selects only results having data in joined table.

`LEFT JOIN` selects all results and attach data from the joined table.

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $jobseekers = JobSeekers
        ::when($request->get('query'), function($query) use ($request) {
            $words = explode(' ', $request->get('query'));
            foreach($words as $word){
                $query->orWhere('job_seekers.category', 'like', '%' . $word . '%');
                $query->orWhere('job_seekers.keywords', 'like', '%' . $word . '%');
                $query->orWhere('job_seekers.experience', 'like', '%' . $word . '%');
            }
        })
        ->leftJoin('ratings', 'job_seekers.id', '=', 'ratings.js_id')
        ->groupBy('job_seekers.id')
        ->select('job_seekers.id', DB::raw('AVG( ratings.rating )  AS average_rating'))
        ->orderBy('average_rating', 'desc')
        ->get();

    return view('search.search_all', compact('jobseekers'));
}
```

Comment: thank you :)
i have a generalization table i.e user is one table and jobseeker and employer is another table. so how can i get data of user of that js_id .

Comment: @ROSHNI do you have relations?

Comment: yes
Schema::create('job_seekers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
});
and user has email , firstname, lastname;